# How do I find the selected element from a ListView in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app that gets a list of contacts and puts them into a ListView. I plan on saving the phone number into a variable, but for now I have it being displayed into a Toast message so I can confirm the value is correct.

AddNewAlarm.kt

```
package com.example.safetybuddy

import android.content.ContentResolver
import android.database.Cursor
import android.location.Location.convert
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.ContactsContract
import android.telephony.PhoneNumberUtils
import android.view.View
import android.widget.AdapterView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.view.get
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_add_new_alarm.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_users.*
import java.util.logging.Logger.global


class AddNewAlarm : AppCompatActivity() {

    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_new_alarm)

        // code to make the button work
        val button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.btnAdd)
        button.setOnClickListener{
            // populate the listView
            populate()
        }

        // get the number when an item is clicked
        listView.setOnItemClickListener{ _,_,pos,_ ->
            Toast.makeText(this, listView.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

        }

    private fun populate(){

        // defines the columns
        var cols = listOf<String>(
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,
            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone._ID

        ).toTypedArray()

        var from = listOf<String>(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER).toTypedArray()

        var to = intArrayOf(android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2)

        var rs = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, cols, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME) // sorts by display name

        var adapter = SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, rs, from, to, 0)

        listView.adapter = adapter
    }
}
```

I am able to populate the ListView, but it doesn't display the phone numbers when I tap the item

Answer (score 0):

`listview.getItemAtPosition(pos)` returns `CursorWrapper`, You have to fetch column values from `CursorWrapper`.

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener{ _,_,pos,_ ->
            val cw : CursorWrapper = listView.getItemAtPosition(pos) as CursorWrapper;
            val str: String = cw.getString(1);
            Toast.makeText(this, str, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been messing with this for weeks and this is the only that that has worked.